# Asian Option with Geometric Averaging

Tags: asian-option

Can someone point me to any notes on how to derive the closed form formula for Asian geometric average option with payoff $\text{max}\left(\text{log}\left(\frac{A_T}{K}\right), 0\right)$ where $A_T$ is given by

$$
A_T=\text{exp}\left(\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T \text{log}(S_u) du \right)
$$

We can assume that the stock follows a GBM as in the black scholes model.

Comment: I changed the small $t$ to capital $T$ in the definition of $A_T$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^T\ln S_u du &= \int_0^T\Big[\big(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\big)u + \sigma W_u  \Big] du\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\big(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\big)T^2 + \sigma\int_0^T\int_0^u dW_s \,du\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\big(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\big)T^2 + \sigma\int_0^T\int_s^T du \,dW_s\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\big(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\big)T^2 + \sigma\int_0^T(T -s) \,dW_s,\\
\end{align*}
which is normally distributed. Then
\begin{align*}
\ln \frac{A_T}{K} &= \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T\ln S_u\, du -\ln K\\
&\sim N\left(\frac{1}{2}\big(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\big)T-\ln K, \ \Big(\frac{\sigma T}{\sqrt{3}}\Big)^2 \right)\\
&=\mu + \Sigma\, \xi,
\end{align*}
where $\mu = \frac{1}{2}\big(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\big)T -\ln K$, $\Sigma = \frac{\sigma T}{\sqrt{3}}$, and $\xi$ is standard normal random variable.
 Consequently, the option payoff has value
\begin{align*}
e^{-rT} E\left(\max\Big(\ln \frac{A_T}{K}, \, 0 \Big) \right) &= e^{-rT} E\left(\max\big(\mu + \Sigma\, \xi, \, 0 \big) \right)\\
&=\frac{e^{-rT}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\frac{\mu}{\Sigma}}^{\infty} (\mu+\Sigma \, x) e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx\\
&=e^{-rT}\bigg[\mu \Phi\Big(\frac{\mu}{\Sigma}\Big)+\frac{\Sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \, e^{-\frac{\mu^2}{2\Sigma^2}}\bigg],
\end{align*}
where $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function of a standard normal random variable.